# GitHub Actions workflow error: Permission denied

Tags: docker, github-actions

I'm running a GitHub Actions workflow and it is failing with the following error.

```
Unhandled exception:
FileSystemException: Cannot create file, path = '/github/home/.flutter' (OS Error: Permission denied, errno = 13)
```

I looked in [Workflow syntax for GitHub Actions](https://help.github.com/en/articles/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions) but couldn't find any instruction to solve this.

My build file is looking like this:

```
name: Flutter CI

on: [push]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    container:
      image:  cirrusci/flutter:v1.7.8-hotfix.4

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v1
    - name: Install dependencies
      run: flutter pub get
      working-directory: my_app
    - name: Run tests
      run: flutter test
```

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/34824

Comment: @Adiii I don't see how it is related, GitHub is now allowing me to create the file in their own volume.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to build Flutter in GitHub Actions CI/CD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57808152/how-to-build-flutter-in-github-actions-ci-cd)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Finally got the time to look at it and adding `sudo` solved it.

The image runs with user `cirrus`. It is also required to provide the full path:

```
sudo /home/cirrus/sdks/flutter/bin/flutter pub get
```

From GitHub [docs](https://help.github.com/en/articles/virtual-environments-for-github-actions#about-virtual-environments):

> The Linux and macOS virtual machines both run using passwordless sudo.
>   When you need to execute commands or install tools that require more
>   privileges than the current user, you can use sudo without needing to
>   provide a password.

Answer (score 10):

Instead of adding sudo to all the steps that fail you can also just modify the container configuration:

```
container:
  image:  cirrusci/flutter:v1.7.8-hotfix.4
  options: --user root
```

Explanation: The problem is being caused because the default user on the cirrusci/flutter:v1.7.8-hotfix.4 image doesn't have access to certain directories that are mounted into this docker image by github. Including the `/github` directory that is causing trouble for you. Adding `options: --user root` to the container configuration makes sure that the default user becomes root so that you do not need to sudo at every single step.

Comment: Can you give a more complete example? Also, what if you don't want to specify the image and have it use the default its currently using?